# Instagram API Request Limit Max 200 only? (2018 April)

Tags: instagram, http-status-code-429

Anyone know the limit request for the Instagram API Token? Since Mar 30, the IG is not showing the posts from IG. As I have more than 20 sites using the same API request.

This is the error given by the API url:

```
{
  "error_type": "OAuthRateLimitException",
  "code": 429,
  "error_message": "You have exceeded the maximum number of requests per hour. You have performed a total of 216 requests in the last hour. Our general maximum limit is set at 200 requests per hour."
}
```

Kindly let me know if anyone has fixed this issue.

Comment: It clearly says the limit is 200 and you have done more than that. What are you actually asking?

Comment: The sites are working well over the past 2 years, everyday the request is more than 200 , but out of a sudden IG/Facebook just decided to cut off the limit to 200 ?

Comment: Is the quota the same? I mean, if you use 200 request from a phone and then you use your Instagram, will Instagram keep working?

Answer (score 1):

It used to 5000 request per user per hour, but suddenly instagram changed this limit to 200 request per hour per user.

Although no official communication.  I found this in their documentation.

The Instagram API uses the same rate limiting as the Graph API (200 calls per user per hour) with one exception: the /media/comments edge limits writes to 60 writes per user per hour. Please refer to the Graph API's rate limiting documentation for more information.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview/#rate-limiting

https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/02/instagram-api-limit/

Hope this will be helpful.